# What kind of spider is this (East Texas)?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

My wife has seen this spider in a shower in Texas:
[image: Spider in East Texas]

What kind of spider is it?

I could not identify it by comparing it to pictures of common spiders in Texas.

Size: It is sitting on corrugated sheet iron in the picture. The legs span from the "top of one wave to the next". The body is "between" the waves.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please [edit] your post to include as much of the following essential information as possible to improve your chances of getting a good answer: 0) when observed; 1) size estimate (Is there a standard wave length of corrugated sheet iron and what is it?) 2) clearer photos — ideally from multiple angles; 3) habitat information; and 4) any observed behavior. [Detailed tag info page](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info). ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a fishing spider, Dolomedes genus, from the tenebrossus group (i.e. not Dolmedes Triton).

The picture is not clear enough to reliably choose a species, but it is probably Dolomedes tenebrosus (dark fishing spider) or Dolomedes vittatus (banded fishing spider), both of which are in Texas.